# Why is matplotlib's notched boxplot folding back on itself?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to make a notched boxplot using matplotlib, but found the notched box tends to overextend and then fold back on itself. This does not happen when I make a regular boxplot.

This can be seen with the following code and the resulting plot that gets generated:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[-0.056, -0.037, 0.010, 0.077, 0.082],
        [-0.014, 0.021, 0.051, 0.073, 0.079]]

# Set 2 plots with vertical layout (1 on top of other)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

ax1.boxplot(data, 1) #Notched boxplot
ax2.boxplot(data, 0) #Standard boxplot

ax1.set_ylim([-0.1, 0.1])
ax2.set_ylim([-0.1, 0.1])

plt.show()
```

[image: Bad Notched Boxplot and Std. boxplot]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: This looks to me like a potential matplotlib bug. Have you tried reporting this on their GitHub repo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means that the distribution of the data is skewed.
If two boxes' notches do not overlap, there is 95% confidence their medians differ.

The Notch displays the confidence interval around the median which is normally based on : [image]

[image]

Maybe, you can alter the [`bootstrap`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) parameter of the `boxplot` to tighten up the median's confidence interval.

Note that the labels for the Upper and Lower whiskers in the displayed image is incorrect. They should read "Lesser of 75th percentile + 1.5*IQR or maximum value" and "Greater of 25th percentile - 1.5*IQR or minimum value" respectively.

Comment: @Nickli Maveli - So, if I understand this correctly - "The size of the notch is indicative of the uncertainty in the value of the median. If that uncertainty is larger than the box size, one will see the folding I observed." .  I was a little confused by your first sentence "It means ... medians differ", since it really is the sort of observation one should make *after* understanding what determines the width of the notch.

Comment: Spot on. You could take that as a digression as I was basically illustrating about the structure of the notch formed.

Answer (score 1):

This aspect of the `notch` is now mentioned in a [Note their docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html):

> In cases where the values of the CI [Confidence Interval] are less than the lower quartile
> or greater than the upper quartile, the notches will extend beyond the
> box, giving it a distinctive "flipped" appearance. This is expected
> behavior and consistent with other statistical visualization packages.