# Why doesn't ggplot show the error bar of a boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, boxplot, errorbar

I was doing some boxplots with ggplot in R and I wonder why it does not show the error bar for just one boxplot ?
[image]
The code was simply this one :

```
ID1.4.5.6.7[,"Time"] <- as.factor(ID1.4.5.6.7[,"Time"])
ggplot(data=ID1.4.5.6.7,aes(x=Time, y=mRNA, fill=Time)) +
  geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE) +
  
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar")+
  
  labs(title="mRNA vs Time", subtitle="Irradiated",x = "Time [min]",y = "mRNA")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I do not know if it is a problem related to the code or it is not a problem but just something related to the data

```
structure(list(Gene = c("ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", 
"ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-1", 
"ID-1", "ID-1", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", 
"ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-4", 
"ID-4", "ID-4", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", 
"ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", 
"ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-5", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", 
"ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", 
"ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-6", "ID-7", "ID-7", 
"ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", 
"ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7", "ID-7"
), mRNA = c(-0.181385669, -0.059647494, 0.104476117, -0.052190978, 
-0.040484945, 0.194226742, -0.501601326, 0.102342605, -0.127143845, 
-0.008523742, -0.102946211, -0.042894028, 0.002922923, -0.134394347, 
-0.214204393, -0.138122686, 0.203242361, 0.097935502, 0.147068146, 
-0.089430917, 0.331565412, -0.034572422, -0.129896329, 0.324191, 
0.470108479, -0.027268223, 0.232304713, 0.090348708, 0.070848402, 
0.181540708, -0.502255367, -0.267631441, -0.368647839, -0.040910404, 
-0.003983171, -0.003983171, -0.003983171, -0.14980589, -0.119449612, 
-0.309154214, -0.487589361, 0.272803506, -0.421733575, -0.467108567, 
0.024868338, -0.156025729, -0.044680175, -0.206716896, -0.272014193, 
-0.230499883, -0.238597397, -0.118130949, 0.349957464, 0.349957464, 
0.349957464, 0.172048587, -0.186226994, 0.16113822, -0.293029136, 
-0.111636253, -0.044189887, 0.081555274, -0.048106079, -0.05853566, 
0.010407814, -0.066981809, -0.09828484, -0.315190986, -0.005102456, 
0.221556197, 0.206584568, 0.206584568, 0.206584568, 0.102649006, 
-0.011777384, -0.36963487, -0.054853074, -0.230240699, -0.210508323, 
-0.208889919, -0.050763372, 0.023073782, -0.095118984, -0.091076071, 
-0.330257395), Time = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("0", 
"20", "40", "60", "120"), class = "factor"), predicted_mRNA = c(-0.00551000342030954, 
-0.00551000342030954, -0.00551000342030954, -0.0302695238715682, 
-0.0302695238715682, -0.00551000342030954, -0.0302695238715682, 
-0.0302695238715682, -0.0550290443228268, -0.0550290443228268, 
-0.0550290443228268, -0.0550290443228268, -0.129307605676603, 
-0.129307605676603, -0.129307605676603, -0.00551000342030954, 
-0.00551000342030954, -0.00551000342030954, -0.0302695238715682, 
-0.0302695238715682, -0.00551000342030954, -0.0302695238715682, 
-0.0302695238715682, -0.0550290443228268, -0.0550290443228268, 
-0.0550290443228268, -0.0550290443228268, -0.129307605676603, 
-0.129307605676603, -0.129307605676603, -0.129307605676603, -0.00551000342030954, 
-0.00551000342030954, -0.00551000342030954, 0.0192495170309491, 
0.0192495170309491, 0.0192495170309491, -0.0302695238715682, 
-0.0302695238715682, -0.00551000342030954, -0.0302695238715682, 
-0.0302695238715682, -0.0550290443228268, -0.0550290443228268, 
-0.0550290443228268, -0.129307605676603, -0.129307605676603, 
-0.129307605676603, -0.129307605676603, -0.00551000342030954, 
-0.00551000342030954, -0.00551000342030954, 0.0192495170309491, 
0.0192495170309491, 0.0192495170309491, -0.0302695238715682, 
-0.0302695238715682, -0.00551000342030954, -0.0302695238715682, 
-0.0302695238715682, -0.0550290443228268, -0.0550290443228268, 
-0.0550290443228268, -0.0550290443228268, -0.129307605676603, 
-0.129307605676603, -0.129307605676603, -0.00551000342030954, 
-0.00551000342030954, -0.00551000342030954, 0.0192495170309491, 
0.0192495170309491, 0.0192495170309491, -0.0302695238715682, 
-0.00551000342030954, -0.0302695238715682, -0.0302695238715682, 
-0.0550290443228268, -0.0550290443228268, -0.0550290443228268, 
-0.0550290443228268, -0.129307605676603, -0.129307605676603, 
-0.129307605676603, -0.129307605676603)), row.names = c(NA, -85L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the dput(ID1.4.5.6.7) so the dataframe.

Comment: Could you please `dput(ID1.4.5.6.7)` and add to the question in order to help you??

Comment: The error bar is there as you can see from the vertical line passing through the box. Therefore I guess that the horizontal lines at the end of the errorbar overlap with the outline of the box.

Comment: @stefan the horizontal lines are at value Q1+-1.5xIQR ? So this value should be equal to  the outliers ? What do you mean when you say "outline"?

Comment: ... the lower and upper boundaries of the box. Additionally. I checked your code on the data in your former post and everything worked fine.

Comment: @Duck I added what you asked

Comment: I think this behaviour comes from using `notch = TRUE`, see an [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795446/12647315)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this approach where you can enable `varwidth` in order to see the error bar. Here the code:

```
#Plot
ggplot(data=ID1.4.5.6.7,aes(x=Time, y=mRNA, fill=Time)) +
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE,notch=TRUE) +
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar")+
  labs(title="mRNA vs Time", subtitle="Irradiated",x = "Time [min]",y = "mRNA")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Because boxplots do not have error bars.  A boxplot is just a graphical representation of five numbers: Minimum, Q1 (1st quartile), Median, Q3 (3rd quartile), and Maximum. The whiskers (the "bars" going up and down) are just lines ending in the minimum value in the data (the lower one) and the maximum value (the upper one). The bottom edge of the "box" is Q1 and the top edge is Q3.

It is possible for a group of data to be arranged such that the minimum is the same as Q1 and the maximum is the same as Q3. More or less, that seems to be what's happening in the boxplot that has no whiskers. ggplot has some extra details added to the boxplot (the "waist" that is pulled in, and an algorithmic tweak that leads to the possibility of the inversion you see at the top of the Time 0 group), but more or less that seems to be what's happening.

*Edit*: This seems to be a question about code, but it's actually about statistics. It might be better for crossvalidated (though I think it is probably sufficiently answered, now).

Comment: I think the implementation of a boxplot in `ggplot2` is not completely the same as you described: ["The upper whisker extends from the hinge to the largest value no further than 1.5 * IQR from the hinge"](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html)

Comment: There are two common ways to draw whiskers in box and whisker plots (https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/131/boxplot.pdf).  A SKELETAL whisker extends to the max/min value.  A SCHEMATIC whisker typically extends 1.5x the IQR (but you can adjust it with `geom_boxplot()` `coef` argument.  Tukey chose 1.5x because if the data is approximately normally distributed that should cover about 95% of the data.

Comment: @starja and itsMeinMiami: Yes, in  my answer I alluded to the 1.5 IQR rule a couple of times but the OP thinks boxplots have error bars, so I didn't want to add too much detail, just to emphasize that their boxplot is not broken; it is probably accurately showing the data. The expectation of error bars was the problem; once OP understands whiskers aren't error bars, I hope most of this question is resolved. The question was based on a misunderstanding of a stats/graphing concept, not a problem with code.